# How to pass through complex command line arguments in Process.Arguments?

Tags: c#, powershell, ffmpeg

In C#, I have a complex set of arguments to pass through to `Process.Arguments`. I have circumvented the problem by using a one-line script of compiled Powershell. The exact "train" of arguments is:

```
ffmpeg -framerate $fr -f image2 -i $temp\JPEG%01d -c:v libx264 -threads $threads -crf $encqual $video_out
```

Problematic arguments are the `-i` (with the JPEG%01 pattern) & the `-c` argument. I have tried double escaping, but it's not working any way I try. I don't like the `/<arg>: <val>` notation because it conflicts with the `-c:v`. As mentioned, I got it working by pass it off to PowerShell, but that's a hack. The directory also gets parsed because it has spaces.

## ERROR:

"Unable to find a suitable output format for 'C:\Program'
"C:\Program" Invalid argument.

## CODE:

```
Process proc = new Process();
// proc.StartInfo = _fw.CreateProcessStartInfo4Ffmpeg(
      pathTempDir,    output);
proc.StartInfo = _fw.CreateProcessStartInfo4AviGen(pathTempDir, output);
proc.Start();

// doesn't work yet
public ProcessStartInfo CreateProcessStartInfo4Ffmpeg(string tempFile,
       string output)
{
   string args = FormCmdArgsForFfmpeg(this, tempFile, output);
   ProcessStartInfo psi = CreateProcessStartInfo4Ffmpeg(this, args);
return psi;
}

public static ProcessStartInfo CreateProcessStartInfo4Ffmpeg(
        FfmpegWrapper fw, string args)
 {
   string sExePath = clsRegistry.regInfo.FfmpegExePath;
   ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(sExePath);

   pi.UseShellExecute = false;
   pi.CreateNoWindow = false;
   pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

   pi.Arguments = String.Copy(args);
   string sCmdFmtdMsg = string.Format("Command: ", 
           sExePath, pi.Arguments);
return pi;
} // end CreateProcessStartInfo4AviGen()

// N.B. doesn't work yet; args prob
public static string FormCmdArgsForFfmpeg(FfmpegWrapper fw, 
     string    tempDir, string output)
{
 /* -framerate $framerate -f image2 -i $temp_dir_jpgs\JPEG%01d 
 -c:v libx264 -threads $threads -crf $encode_quality $video_out
 */
    string sFmtdArg2 = "-{0} \"{1}\" ";
    string sFmtdArg1 = "-{0} ";
    string sArgs = String.Empty;
    string sout = null;
    string pathInput = Path.Combine(tempDir, "JPEG%01d");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    sb.Append(string.Format(sFmtdArg2, "framerate", fw.framerate));
    sb.Append(string.Format(sFmtdArg2, "f", "image2"));
    sb.Append(string.Format(sFmtdArg2, "i", pathInput));
    sb.Append(string.Format(sFmtdArg2, "c:v", "libx264"));
    sb.Append(string.Format(sFmtdArg2, "threads", fw.threads) );
    sb.Append(string.Format(sFmtdArg2, "crf", fw.encode_quality));
    sb.Append(output);
    sout = sb.ToString();
return sout;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'forbidden' characters ? What error are you actually getting ? Are you getting an error at all or do you just mean that you have trouble placing this text in a C# string literal ?

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Make sure you show clearly what you've tried, and explain precisely how what the code does now is different from what you want it to do.